# Задать имя маршруту, содержащей переменную. Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Есть роут, содержит переменную и имя: (сначала путь работал без переменной)

```
Route::get('/read/{id}', ['as'=>'read', 'uses' => 'ArticleController@readPage' ] );
```

Есть ссылка на роут по имени:

```
{{ route('read') }}
```

Такая конструкция выдаёт ошибки.

Возможно ли задать имя маршруту с переменной и обращаться к нему по имени?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

передавать в хелпер второй параметр массив со значениями

`{{ route('routeName', ['id' => 1]); }}`

или сделать параметр `id` необязательным добавив знак вопроса `?`

`/read/{id?}`

@AntonMironov спасибо за дополнение, совсем забыл что так тоже можно

Также можно передавать параметры без указания ключа массива. Если параметр всего один, то `{{ route('routeName', 1); }}`. А если несколько - `{{ route('routeName', [1, 2, 3]); }}`

Comment: Также можно передавать параметры без указания ключа массива. Если параметр всего один, то `{{ route('routeName', 1); }}`. А если несколько - `{{ route('routeName', [1, 2, 3]); }}`